# RenderFlex overflowed email.toString() - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences, tostring, flutter-renderflex-error

Whenever I am writing Text(email.toString()), it gives the error of RenderFlex overflowed, please help me how to fix it. I am using SharedPreferences.

[image: Before writing Text(email.toString()) - it works fine]

[image: When writing Text(email.toString() - it gives error of RenderFlex overflowed]

Comment: What is the type of your variable `email`?

Comment: Try posting code-snippet instead of code-image. More about [Why should I not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

Add your Text widget inside [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget,
try below code:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text('Email'),
    SizedBox(
      width: 10,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
          'putyouremailaddress@gmail.computyouremailaddress@gmail.com'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result: [image]

Answer (score 0):

replace your Row with this one...

```
Row(
  children: [
    const Text("Email"),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(email.toString()),
    ),
  ],
),
```